# UK Student Visa Application: What defines a Media Company?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, student-visas

On the application form you get asked if you've previously worked at:

Armed Forces (including National Service)

Government (Central or Local)

Judiciary

**Media Organisation**

Public or Civil Administration

Security (including police and private security companies)

I have previously worked as an Assistant Director in a production house under a Director. We use to produce Films, Web Series and Commercial. We were not involved in distribution as we produced and sold the product to companies.

Do I have to select the 'Media Organisation' option or not?

Comment: Usually, where visa applications are concerned, the ‘safe’ approach is *if in doubt, disclose and explain*. That allows the ECO to decide if it matters or not; if not, you are ok and if it does, you’ve told them so still ok. Can’t spot anything on the topic in the guidance https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/976139/student-route-casework-guidance-v3.0-ext.pdf